# Remove Padding on CupertinoSliverNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I am trying to use `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar`, actually it's great, but for some reason I can't place the trailing right on the end of navigation bar. I looked up and I (guess, I) found that there's `Padding` inside it

[image]

this is my code

```
   new CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: new CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            new CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: new Text('Tasks'),
              trailing: new CupertinoButton(
                child: new Icon(AdditionalCupertinoIcons.compose, size: 32.0),
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return new CupertinoAlertDialog();
                      });
                },
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no *can-do*.

Looking at [this line of source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart#L428), you can see that they are using a `Padding` at the end, which is [`_kNavBarEdgePadding`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart#L27), i.e. `16.0`. Same for the `start`.

This means that with the `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar` you will not be able to remove that `Padding` because there is no access point to change it. You will have to create your *own widget* for that.

The [`_CupertinoPersistentNavigationBar` widget](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart#L328) contains the `Padding` and is used by `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar`, as can be [seen here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart#L273) and for completion [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart#L546).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I look at the Widget Tree and yes there's a Padding inside of it. and I just think why it's the default.

Comment: @Ampersanda Because it is *Cupertino* styling and the creator of the class did not bother to make the padding property public by e.g. adding an optional parameter to the constructor. You might want to [create a pull request here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/edit/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart). I think that they might be open for consideration.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to move a widget on the screen:

```
Widget _adjustNavigationBarButtonPosition(Widget button, double x) {
    if (button == null) return null;

    return Container(
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(x, 0, 0),
        child: button,
    );
}
```

Wrap your CupertinoButton with this method and specify an offset. To remove the padding completely, the offset should be `16.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Matrix4.translationValues](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math/Matrix4/Matrix4.translationValues.html) to move a child within the container. In your case x `Matrix4.translationValues(12, 0, 0),` should be positive to move the trailing to the right.

```
 new CupertinoPageScaffold(
    child: new CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        new CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
          largeTitle: new Text('Tasks'),
          trailing: Container(
           transform: Matrix4.translationValues(12, 0, 0),
           child : CupertinoButton(
            child: new Icon(AdditionalCupertinoIcons.compose, size: 32.0),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return new CupertinoAlertDialog();
                  });
            },
            )
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```